# Can't resize any window on Ubuntu. It become not clickable and move to the left top corner

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg, nvidia, intel-graphics

I installed new Ubuntu 18 and it has a bug. When I try to maximize window, it becomes not active/clickable and move to the left top corner. When I drag it again, it becomes active. I tried to reinstall driver, fix dependencies, switch between video drivers, but it doesn't help me.

I attached a screenshot to my question.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fo1rH.png

I also attached a Youtube video because I can't explain it pretty well
[Click this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnW-1w25tqI)

Comment: How are you trying to maximize your window? By clicking the button on the top right window corner or by dragging it to your upper screenboarder?

Comment: When I click maximize button on the top right corner of any app, I get this bug

Comment: I can only resize window by mouse

Comment: Can you check this video? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnW-1w25tqI

Comment: seems like your filemanager is working properly. do you still have problems with all other applications or is it just chromium producing this bug? btw. did you noticed the changes to the titlebarsize during your video? can you reproduce this changing with other apps?